# Gzip compression in Apache Tomcat 8 for image and font

Tags: java, tomcat, gzip, image-compression, http-compression

This is configuration for `gzip` compression in `Apache Tomcat 8`

```
<Connector port="7070" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
       maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
       enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
       connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
       compression="on" 
       compressionMinSize="256" 
       noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
       compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/javascript,font/otf,font/woff,
       font/woff2,image/gif,image/jpg,image/png"/>
```

`png` image is OK. It does not work for `jpg` image and `woff2` font as below.

I already try as below, it does not work

```
image/jpg <or> image/jpeg <or> application/octet-stream

font/woff <or> font/woff2 <or> application/font-woff <or> application/font-woff2
```

Testing From Chrome

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to compress already compressed formats like JPEG and PNG? You won't get any better results and will just waste power.

Comment: I thought, If I can compress images and some resources (eg, jpg, font, png),  the response time will be faster.

Comment: PNG and JPEG are already compressed. You're making the response times worse for them. JS, HTML etc may benefit from compression. For images do optimization beforehand if needed.

Comment: Thanks! well noted! I will re-configure my setting.
But, one strange thing is it is work for `png` but for `jpg` as on image.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to compress already compressed files(gzip) like woff/woff2, jpg etc. From my point of view, it's just resource wasting. Not every type of file can be compressed (see:[Fastly blog about gzip settings](https://www.fastly.com/blog/new-gzip-settings-and-deciding-what-compress/)).

Here's the types Fastly recommends compressing by default:

> Extensions: js css html json ico eot otf ttf
>
> Content Types: text/html application/x-javascript text/css
>   application/javascript text/javascript text/plain text/xml
>   application/json application/vnd.ms-fontobject
>   application/x-font-opentype application/x-font-truetype
>   application/x-font-ttf application/xml font/eot font/opentype font/otf
>   image/svg+xml image/vnd.microsoft.icon